# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual for the right syntax to use near 'AND `user_id` = 1'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I know there are a lot of questions like these out there, but none of them seem to work, I cannot find the error on my syntax!

```
mysql_query("SELECT `type` FROM `poststuff` WHERE `post_id` = 7 AND `user_id` = 1");
```

Any help will be awesome!
(Btw, error is on the title)
Full code (for you people -,-)

```
function update_post($post_id, $user_id) {
$result = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `type` FROM `poststuff` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id AND `user_id` = $user_id"), 0) or die(mysql_error());
if ($result !== null) {
if ($result === "no" ) {
$actual_count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `$result` FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id"), 0);
mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET `$actual_count` = $actual_count+1 WHERE `post_id` = $post_id AND `type` = 'no'");
}
```

Comment: give your table structure

Comment: Are 7 and 1 actually in the query or are they variables?

Comment: Yes they are, and they don't need single quotes since they are integers right?

Comment: Yes, Integers do not need single quotes.

Comment: Since this command has absolutely nothing that checks if it yields an error (EG `or die(mysql_error())1)`, I tend to think this is not the faulty query. Also, the query seems ok.

Comment: Try to execute this query in phpmyadmin and see if it gives same error

Comment: What if you remove the backticks from around ``user_id``?

Comment: I got this error in phpMyAdmin, with only this query!

Comment: @Jaxo: What makes you think that would help?

Comment: @TheBlueDog I've had weird things happen like this before.  For some reason, it didn't like the backticks around my column name.

Comment: @DCV_Diego Show us more of your code

Comment: function update_post($post_id, $user_id) {
 $result = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `type` FROM `poststuff` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id AND `user_id` = $user_id"), 0) or die(mysql_error());
 if ($result !== null) {
 if ($result === "no" ) {
 $actual_count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `$result` FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id"), 0);
 mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET `$actual_count` = $actual_count+1 WHERE `post_id` = $post_id AND `type` = 'no'");
 }

Comment: @DCV_Diego just edit your question and put it in there

Comment: The mysql_* functions do not support placeholders.

Comment: @hd1 of course they do, I've used them before

Comment: @DCV_Diego thinking it is some character encoding problem... If I copy paste your query right from the browser to my mysql workbench, I do not get the above error. Try deleting the query and retyping it (without copy/pasting it)

Comment: @DCV_Diego and also off course check whether your encoding problem doesn't come from where you get the $post_id and $user_id variables.

Comment: @nl-x i've done both of the things u said and it didn't work, I'll try something else...

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a problem in the SQL text that you posted. I recommend you verify that it's a valid white space character preceding the **`AND`** keyword.

Based on the error message, I suspect there's an invalid character preceding the `AND` keyword in the query.

This is the kind of error you would get if you ran a query that had a **comma** or some other non-whitespace character preceding the `AND` keyword.

For example, running this query:

```
SELECT `type` FROM `poststuff` WHERE `post_id` = 7,AND `user_id` = 1
                                                  ^
```

would result in an error like the one you are getting:

```
... error in your SQL syntax; ... near 'AND `user_id` = 1'
```

The same error would be reported if there wasn't a value after the equal sign, and only whitespace. For example the following query would return the same error:

```
SELECT `type` FROM `poststuff` WHERE `post_id` = AND `user_id` = 1
                                                ^
```

Comment: I also thought of this, but when I copy/paste the above into my query browser, I don't get that error. Maybe OP didn't copy paste his query to SO, but retyped it?

Comment: function update_post($post_id, $user_id) {
 $result = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `type` FROM `poststuff` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id AND `user_id` = $user_id"), 0) or die(mysql_error());
 if ($result !== null) {
 if ($result === "no" ) {
 $actual_count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `$result` FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id` = $post_id"), 0);
 mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET `$actual_count` = $actual_count+1 WHERE `post_id` = $post_id AND `type` = 'no'");
 }

Comment: @DCV_Diego Stop and verify what you said before "I got this error in phpMyAdmin, with only this query!" <-- *Is that a true statement, where "this query" is the exact text in the question?*

Comment: Yes, it is a true statement, you guys wanted me to show you the whole code so I did, I know (since I echoed it) that $post_id, and $user_id are in fact, the integers I put on my sql, the error has nothing to do with my code, but with the sql itself

Comment: @DCV_Diego Okay, so this answer proposes that the issue is caused due to an unexpected character rendered as whitespace (or perhaps not shown at all). What happens if you *retype* (no copy/paste!) the original query - `SELECT \`type\` FROM \`poststuff\` WHERE \`post_id\` = 7 AND \`user_id\` = 1` - into phpMyAdmin and run it?

Comment: @DCV_Diego NO WAY you must not be retyping it or you are still using the $variables in it.

Comment: I have to use the $variables, even if I put the actual value, it still does not work

Comment: @DCV_Diego Try to reproduce the issue in SQL fiddle - as [I cannot reproduce the error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f143/1)